# Chrome Sync Now Impossible with i386

Tags: google-chrome, 32-bit, sync

Am I right thinking that there is no workaround to enable Chrome to Sync on an i386 machine?

Access to the API has been withdrawn from Chromium, and no earlier i386 version of Chrome will have access either?

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: chrome and chromium are 2 different products. And no it has nothing to do with i386.  Google blocked all other browsers from leeching of their API.

Comment: I have Xubuntu 18.04 on an i386 machine, no further updates are available, I was using Chromium on this machine, but now Sync fails. So I presume I am now unable to Sync Chromium, and unable to Sync Chrome, because i386 is no longer supported. Is there a workaround or is my understanding correct?